# libpcap for Python2.6 (Windows)

Tags: python, libpcap

Currently want to use libpcap under Python2.6 in windows.

I tried Pypcap, but it only have binary build for python 2.5 or older, pylibpcap seems doesn't have any binary build.

I also can't install them from source, seems that I have to build libpcap first.

I want to develop an app, and then pack it using py2exe, then I want to make sure the lib is simple to install and compatible with py2exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two python libpcap modules that you can use.

1. http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pcapy.html
2. http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/